# Запуск Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, веб-сервер, angular2

Здравствуйте!
Установил Angular 2 на локалке, всё сработало, но когда перевёл на сервер, в консоли выдаёт ошибки.

> compiler.umd.js:1 **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**
>
> platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js:368 **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'XHR' of undefined**
>
> zone.js:260 **Uncaught TypeError: ng.platformBrowserDynamic.bootstrap is not a function**

Comment: Ангуляр так то в браузере работает. Что вы подразумеваете под переводом на сервер?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Ну сначала я установил просто на компе, по инструкции Angular 2 Quick Start, всё нормально работало, потом всё скопировал на сервер, а там выдавались эти ошибки.

Comment: Проверьте в консоли были ли ошибки 404 на загрузку каких-либо скриптов. Скорее всего что-то недокопировали

Comment: Просто скопировал? Если хочешь по стандартной установке, то нужно все зависимости установить. там ведь понимается свой webpack-овский сервер. Плюс собирается html со ссылками на сгенереные js, css и.д. файлы.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно выполнить команду `ng build --prod` в папке с проектом и после завершения операции, в ней же появится папка `dist` в которой будет ваше скомпилированное приложение как набор html, css, js и остальных файлов. Его можно будет загрузить на сервер и использовать.

Подробнее можете почитать в документации: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#basic-deployment-to-a-remote-server